# Ensure stored card is valid without charge or hold?

Tags: balanced-payments

Is there a way to determine if a card stored in Balanced is still valid, without creating a charge or a hold against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to determine if a card is valid without initiating a transaction. Furthermore, even during tokenization while we do offer a series of methods to check a cards validity (e.g. card number, security code, expiration dates) these do not guarantee that transactions made to the card will succeed.